# How to style select/option fields

Tags: html, css

I have a select like so:

```
    <select class="mySelect">
      <option value="1" class="option1">1</option>
      <option value="2" class="option1">2</option>
    </select>
```

Here is the css I am doing:

```
   select option {
     color: red;
     font-style: italic;
    }
```

```css
select option {
     color: red;
     font-style: italic;
    }
```

```html
<select class="mySelect">
          <option value="1" class="option1">1</option>
          <option value="2" class="option1">2</option>
        </select>
```

None of these styles are applying at all

Comment: `.mySelect > option1{color: red;font-style: italic;}` try that. I can see the dropdown options as **red** when I run the code snippet. Try a different browser and change colours. I'm saying change colours cause you might be colour blind ( not joking here).

Comment: You can not style option's cross browser..

Comment: Look at his example you might wanna consider using JS or just copy the styles [Create a Custom Select Menu](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select)